Minimal areal surface given volume and boundary
It is a well-known fact that the surface of minimal area in $R^3$ that encloses a certain amount of volume is the sphere of that volume.
Similarly, lots are known about the minimal areal surfaces having a certain curve in $R^3$ as its boundary (helicoid, hyperboloid, etc)
My question is: What is the minimal areal surface enclosing given amount of volume (so the surface is necessarily closed) such that one of the bounding surfaces of it is the given open surface? For instance, if one has a rectangle, what is the minimal surface having this rectangle as one of the "faces" (this simply means that there is a plane in $R^3$ whose intersection with the surface is this rectangle) and it encloses the given volume?
I suppose this would be very much like a sphere if the size of the open surface is negligible compared to the sphere of the given volume, but I am not sure whether this problem has a definitive answer nor am I aware of any known problems of this nature.
Any help, or pointing to a helpful direction, resources would be much appreciated.

What does your first sentence mean? No closed surface can be minimal. It could have constant mean curvature.

@Deane By minimal surface I meant the surface of minimal surface area.

Could you edit the first sentence?

By convention, such surfaces are not called minimal surfaces. Minimal surfaces are defined to be surfaces with zero mean curvature, even though they don’t always minimize area. The surfaces you want to study have constant mean curvature away from the boundary of the prescribed surface (e.g, the rectangle). I suggest googling for surveys or lecture notes on such surfaces.

They are the CMC or constant mean curvature surfaces visualized by soap films. They are given by the ode $ (k_1+k2)= p/T $ , a constant  where $p$ is pressure and $T$ is surface tension property. The shapes can be found by numerical methods, no closed form is known. The shape smoothly transitions from a rectangle to a sphere.

Area-Volume relation still holds good even when including a rectangular boundary. This is because physical invariants $(p,T)$ the pressure and surface tension are involved.
Equating radius of a sphere from its Volume and Area,
$$ (\frac{A}{4\pi})^3=(\frac{3V}{4\pi})^2\to  A= (36 \pi V^2) ^{\frac13}$$
The Science of Soap Films and Soap Bubbles by Cyril Isenberg. The English book contains a beautiful description of the topic.
Goldschmitt has conditions about stability of films when one or several films are drawn between wireframes... rigid frames counteract surface tension forces.
Three varieties of Delaunay Unduloid surfaces are interesting  surfaces of revolution which are more simple than those generated by polygonal boundaries. You can google to see relevant shapes and  literature. The sphere is a special case.
For zero differential pressure across  a surface of revolution film is governed by CMC $2H= \kappa_1+\kappa_2=0.$ For nonzero differential pressure its ode is of the form ($\lambda$ a real constant, $H$ is mean film/surface curvature:
$$\kappa_1 = H+\frac{\lambda}{r^2}, ~ \kappa_2 = H-\frac{\lambda}{r^2};$$
To realize its form practically, dip a rectangular wireframe in a soap solution and gently blow air from mouth towards the center of rectangle. We can just about manage to see several shapes expanding when pressure increases.
The midline curvature changes sign negative to positive somewhat schematically as:

Unduloid

Why did you promote this comment to an answer?

I find occasionally in this site some comments as good as answers.
